# Hooking into Qi charger status LED to power something more

Tags: transistors, led, relay, wireless-charging

I have a Qi charging module and I want to light up a higher-power string of LEDs when my phone is charging through it.

The module has a blue status LED to show it's charging, which I think is where I would hook into. My question is, could I use a transistor or relay where the status LED is to switch on my string of lights. Or, should I use some sort of current monitoring on the coil instead of relying on the status LED?

I'm kinda new to hobby electronics so sorry if I've made some silly assumptions along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Check what IC is used in this charger. Get the datasheet and check the sink/source capability of that pin.
A bipolar transistor would probably work, a logic level FET would work, a relay is unlikely to work, due to the pin not having enough drive current.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the IC doesn't have any markings, but it's only cheap so if I try a bipolar transistor or logic level FET and it breaks it's no big deal ;)